# Hosting ReactJS with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, web-applications, hosting

We are in the final stages developing a web application. It has a front-end in React and a back-end in Laravel. They communicate by sending JSONs back and forth (API style), so they can be hosted on seperate servers without many problems.

During development we switched to Firebase, because this way we could host React for free, but we need some logic in the back-end and Firebase is not ideal for this.

What is the best solution to host an application that uses React for the front-end and Laravel for the back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic question. There are plenty of hosting providers out there - [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com), [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com), [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com) to name a few.

To decide which one is the `best`, you need to provide more information:

- What matters most to you? Pricing, support, availability, technology solutions / capabilities, ease of scaling?
- What's your tech stack, starting with database, caching, CDNs, etc.(the whole works)? Laravel and ReactJS alone does not describe your tech stack unless you're using local file drivers for everything (such as sessions, cache, config) and SQLite as your DB.

Comment: To us the most important things are pricing and ease-of-use, as we are still students. Our tech stack consists of React as the front-end, with Laravel running in the back and using a MySQL database on standard shared hosting.

Comment: I'd go for AWS free tier in that case. Use RDS, EC2 (all micro and free for a year). There's no `right` answer though, everything is subjective

Comment: Thank you, we will try that!